# Design a subclass of dict whose iterator would return its keys in sorted order

Tags: python, iterator

This is an exercise from [Python Epiphanies](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mgg45Wr8jY). The original question:

> Design a subclass of dict whose iterator would return its keys, as
>   does dict, but in sorted order, and **without using yield**.

I came up with a solution which seems to work:

```
>>> class mydict(dict):
        def __iter__(self):
            self.index = 0
            self.sorted_keys = sorted(self.keys())
            self.it = iter(self.sorted_keys)
            return self
        def __next__(self):
            if self.index < len(self.keys()):
                self.index += 1
                next(self.it)
                return self.sorted_keys[self.index-1]
            else:
                raise StopIteration


>>> d = mydict({2: 1, 4: 5, 3: 7, 1: 2})
>>> dit = iter(d)
>>> next(dit)
1
>>> next(dit)
2
>>> next(dit)
3
>>> next(dit)
4
>>> next(dit)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#96>", line 1, in <module>
    next(dit)
  File "<pyshell#89>", line 13, in __next__
    raise StopIteration
StopIteration
```

Since no standard answer is provided, I just want to know if this is the **optimal answer**.
Thank you.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. The `self.it` attribute isn't doing anything, and more importantly, you can't get two independent iterators over the same `mydict`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply return an iterator from the `__iter__` like this,

```
class mydict(dict):
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(sorted(super(mydict, self).__iter__()))

d = mydict({2: 1, 4: 5, 3: 7, 1: 2})
dit = iter(d)
print next(dit)  # 1
print next(dit)  # 2
print next(dit)  # 3
print next(dit)  # 4
print next(dit)  # StopIteration
```

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21310344/1903116) for a complete implementation of `SortedDict`.

Answer (score 1):

You can return an iterator on the dict keys.

```
class mydict(dict):
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(sorted(self.keys()))

>>> d = mydict({ 3: 1, 8:2, 4:3,2:2})
>>> for x in d: print x
... 
2
3
4
8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sorted_keys(dict):
    return '\n'.join(sorted(dict.keys()))
dict={'c':'c', 'b':'b', 'a':'a'}
print sorted_keys(dict)
```