# Sorting dictionary for printing

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, printing

I want to print a sorted dictionary, which contains a lot of key value pairs (~2000).
Each pair consists of a number as the key and a string as the value.
It is just about printing, i don't want to sort the dictionary actually.

If i use the `sorted()` method, python sorts my dictionary, but in an awkward way:

```
{'0':'foo', '1':'bar', '10': 'foofoo', '100': 'foobar', '1000': 'barbar', 
 '1001': 'barfoo', '1002': 'raboof', ...}
```

But I want to sort it the 'conventional' way like this:

```
{'0':'foo', '1':'bar', '2': 'foofoo', '3': 'foobar', '4': 'barbar', 
 '5': 'barfoo', ... , '1001': 'raboof'}
```

Can I force the method to behave how I want to, or is there another better solution?

Comment: Why not use a list instead? Your numbers appear to be sequential, why use a dictionary at all?

Comment: Because it is faster loading the values than a list.

Comment: Not for indices, it isn't. `listobj[10]` will return the 11th value faster than `dictobj['10']` because the dictionary has to hash and perturb the key first.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks... didn't knew that

Comment: But filling the list with information will take longer than the dictionary, btw...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your keys are strings representing integers; if you want a numeric sort, use `int()` to turn the keys to integers:

```
sorted(yourdict, key=int)
```

gives you a numerically sorted list of keys and

```
sorted(yourdict.items(), key=lambda i: int(i[0]))
```

gives you items sorted by the numeric value of the key.

However, if you have sequential keys starting at 0, you should be using a list object instead. Index references are faster than dictionary lookups as there is no hashing step required.

Even if your keys do not start at 0 but are still sequential, for a small start index you'd just pad the list with `None` values:

```
[None, 'foo', 'bar', 'foofoo', ...]
```

and index into that starting at 1.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot sort the dictionary, because they are naturally unordered (they use hashing internally), but you can print the key-value pairs in the sorted way

```
print sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x: int(x[0]))
```

**Output**

```
[('0', 'foo'),
 ('1', 'bar'),
 ('10', 'foofoo'),
 ('100', 'foobar'),
 ('1000', 'barbar'),
 ('1001', 'barfoo'),
 ('1002', 'raboof')]
```

If you want to iterate through the dictionary in the sorted manner, *by default*, then you can use the custom `SortedDict` class from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21310344/1903116)

Also, you can print the dictionary in sorted way, like this

```
print "{{{}}}".format(", ".join(["{!r}: {!r}".format(key, d[key]) for key in sorted(d, key=int)]))
# {'0': 'foo', '1': 'bar', '10': 'foofoo', '100': 'foobar', '1000': 'barbar', '1001': 'barfoo', '1002': 'raboof'}
```

Comment: Your `SortedDict` would need to support a `key` function though.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use string as keys. You can use integers:

```
dct = {0:'foo', 1:'bar', 10: 'foofoo', 2: 'foo2'}
```

If you need strings then add `key` argument to `sorted()`. In your case it will be `int` for converting string int integer:

```
sorted(dct, key=int)
```